# DirectX - Blur objects according to z coordinate of the object

Tags: 3d, directx, motion-blur

I want to blur objects in my 3D scene according to the object's z coordinate (the coordinate going into the screen). Say for z=5 blur amount=0, z=10 blur=50, z=-30 blur=40. This has to happen for every object.

1. How can I do this?
2. Do I have to use directx 9.0c or up to implement this (because of shaders)?

Do I make use of the Z buffer? I'm a bit new to DirectX.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [Depth of field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field) Here is some [nice reading](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch28.html) And yes its require shaders.

To achieve simple DOF you can render scene twice:

1. Render to texture far half (with front culling in the midle and
   back culling in the end of scene).
2. Render quad with this texture(blure it with simple shader).
3. Render front half on top  (with back  culling in the middle of
   scene)